# System of 2 equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve the system of equations:

> $$
> \left\{\begin{matrix}2\sqrt{x+y} = y^2+y-x & \quad(1) \\ x(y^2+y)=(y^4-y^2)^2-2  & \quad(2) \end{matrix}\right.
> $$

**My attempt:**

From $(1)$ I get:

$$(1) \implies (\sqrt{x+y}+y+2)(\sqrt{x+y}-y) = 0$$

So either $\sqrt{x+y}+y+2 = 0 \implies x = y^2+3y+4$ or $\sqrt{x+y}-y = 0 \implies x = y^2-y$. If I replace either of them into $(2)$, It would be very messy since this will become a $8$th-degree polynomial.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=y^2-y$ so
$$y^4-y^2=(y^4-y^2)^2-2,$$
which gives $$y^4-y^2=-1,$$ which is impossible, or
$$y^4-y^2=2.$$
Can you end it now?

I got that the second case: $$\sqrt{x+y}+y+2=0$$ is impossible.

Indeed, $y\leq-2$ and $$x+y=(y+2)^2$$ or
$$x=y^2+3y+4,$$ which gives
$$(y^2+3y+4)(y^2+y)=(y^4-y^2)^2-2$$ or
$$y^8-2y^6-4y^3-7y^2-4y-2=0$$ or
$$y^8-4y^6+2y^6-8y^4+8y^4-32y^2-4y^3+25y^2-100-4y+98=0$$ or
$$(y^2-4)(y^6+2y^4+8y^2+25)-4y^3-4y+98=0,$$ which is impossible for $y\leq-2$.

Comment: Can we prove the second case is impossible?

Comment: @windows prime I added something. See now.

Answer (score 1):

If we substitute $x=y^2-y$ we can factor $(2)$ as
$$(y^2-2)(y^2+1)(y^4-y^2+1)=0$$
and we get $y=\pm\sqrt2,\pm i,\pm w,\pm w^*$ where $w=e^{i\pi/6}$. Only $y=\sqrt2,i,w,w^*$ lead to equality in $(1)$ under the principal square root. If $x=y^2+3y+4$ we get an irreducible octic in $y$ with two real roots and three complex conjugate root pairs, but all of them do not lead to equality in $(1)$ if the principal square root is taken.

Comment: Can we prove that within the second case, we can't find a solution to the system of equations?

Comment: @windowsprime Yes. Just numerically solve the octic and see that taking the principal root in $(1)$ does not lead to equality.

Comment: @EricTowers ...I just wrote that into my answer.

Comment: Out of sync with updates...

Comment: @EricTowers Wolfram Alpha gives me $7$ different roots with $2$ real roots and $5$ complex roots

Comment: @windowsprime : And Mathematica gives four solutions of the given system, two of which initially use roots of $u^4-2u^3+2u^2+2u+1 = 0$, but can be simplified greatly.

Comment: @windowsprime You didn't click on "more solutions", eh? It is impossible for a real polynomial to have $5$ complex roots!

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yes It was my mistake. Now I tried to enter the original system of equations and  I get only 1 real solution.

Comment: @windowsprime And I have shown that it is the only real one. $y=\sqrt2,x=2-\sqrt2$.